# isAlpha or isAlphanumeric in dataweave not working as expected

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have 2 keys in payload for which I want to validate the values, here are the scenarios

```
{
    "System" : "ABC",
    "Number" : 123.45
},
{
    "System" : "ABC123",
    "Number" : "123abc"
}
```

I want to validate if the string "System" only contains Characters and not any numbers.

I tried `isAlphanumeric(payload[0].system)` or `contains(payload[0].system, /^[0-9]+$/` but that will still not give me correct result. how do I make sure System only has characters and not is not alphanumeric?

Same for the Number, I want to validate if the number field has any character or not? If I use `isNumeric(payload[0].number)` it does not validate decimal and return false if number has decimals, if I use `isDecimal(payload[0].number)` and if number is `1234` is does not validate that.

How do I validate these 2 fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that in your example you're mixing `String` and `Number` types for the same field; `isDecimal` requires a `Number`, and is only used to determine if the `Number` is a decimal number or not. When you call it you already need to know if its a `Number` type. If you want to be able to mix and match types:

Input:

```json
[{
    "System" : "ABC",
    "Number" : 123.45
},
{
    "System" : "ABC123",
    "Number" : "123abc"
},
{
    "System": "AAAA-AAA",
    "Number": "1234"
},
{
    "System": "KLDJSKL2123",
    "Number": 123
},
{
    "System": "KLDJSLKFJ",
    "Number": "123.45"
}]
```

Dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
import isAlpha from dw::core::Strings

var isNumericOrDecimal = (str: Number | String) ->
    str match {
        case is Number -> true
        case str matches /^[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?/ -> true
        else -> false 
    }

output application/json
---
payload map { System: isAlpha($.System), Number: isNumericOrDecimal($.Number) }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "System": true,
    "Number": true
  },
  {
    "System": false,
    "Number": false
  },
  {
    "System": false,
    "Number": true
  },
  {
    "System": false,
    "Number": true
  },
  {
    "System": true,
    "Number": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try this. somehow dwlang.fun decided to go offline for no reason.

Comment: @apple123 - you can self-host the playground, fyi. There is both a CLI and a docker container that can be used to launch your own instance locally.

Comment: @apple123 You can also try this https://dwl.mule.club/

Comment: WOW, never knew about the CLI for dw. I am going to definitely try that, meanwhile, let me try dwl.mule.club

Comment: @apple123 https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-native you can install it via homebrew and then launch your own playground `dw --eval --spell Playground`. I prefer the docker container though because I just have it always running

Comment: @MichaelJones Thank you for your time on this, this seems to be working, I am testing right now. I would really appreciate it if you can explain to me what the regEx is doing? vI want to understand better for future use.

Comment: @apple123 - Take a look at https://regex101.com - it will break the regex down for you. I didn't write this regex, but it's meant to match a whole host of things. eg: `-1.9E-10` is valid; its supporting scientific notation. You might not want that; however, dataweave does support it when converting strings to numbers!

Comment: @apple123 Basically it has an optional + or - at the start, then between 0 and infinity numeric characters, then optionally a decimal, and then at least 1 up to infinity numeric characters, and then as a non-capturing group that can occur 0 or 1 time as a whole: an e or E (at least one!) followed by an optional sign and between 1 and infinity digits.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation, I just had one more question, should I post it separately or can I ask you here in chat? it's similar to these fields

Comment: @apple123 - that depends largely on if its related to some tweak to the solution or a separate (even if related) question. The point of stackoverflow is to help people find answers to their questions, so if it can stand as its own question I would do a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229696/discussion-between-michael-jones-and-apple123).